# Cannot install .NET 3.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 with Chef Test Kitchen

Tags: .net-3.5, chef-infra

I could not find a way to install .NET 3.5 with Chef Test Kitchen on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I can install the framework from the command line with

`C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart /All /source:"C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\dotnetfx35.exe"`

or from the PowerShell prompt with

`Install-WindowsFeature –name NET-Framework-Core –source "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\dotnetfx35.exe"`

but if I execute any of the following in chef I get the same error:

> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
>
> Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Enabling feature(s)
>
> Error: 0x800f0906
>
> The source files could not be downloaded.
>
> Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are
>   required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a
>   source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink....

I have copied the dotnetfx35.exe to the user's temp directory at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\dotnetfx35.exe

**chef --version**

> Chef Development Kit Version: 0.15.16
>
> chef-client version: 12.11.18
>
> delivery version: master (444effdf9c81908795e88157f01cd667a6c43b5f)
>
> berks version: 4.3.5 kitchen version: 1.7.3

The resources I have tried so far:

**Using Chocolatey**:

```
chocolatey_package 'dotnet3.5' do
  options "--allow-empty-checksums --ignore-package-exit-codes"
end
```

**Execute**:

```
  execute 'install_dot_net_3-5' do
    command "C:\\Windows\\system32\\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart /All /source:\"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dotnetfx35.exe\""
    timeout 9999
  end
```

**Batch**:

```
  batch 'install_dot_net_3-5' do
    code <<-EOH
      C:\\Windows\\system32\\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart /All /source:"C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dotnetfx35.exe"
    EOH
    cwd "#{ENV['TEMP']}"
    timeout 9999
  end
```

**Powershell script**:

```
  powershell_script 'install_dot_net_3-5' do
    code <<-EOH
      Install-WindowsFeature –name NET-Framework-Core –source "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dotnetfx35.exe"
    EOH
  end
```

Comment: Test kitchen runs the chef recipes inside a VM. Any temp files probably won't be available and the vm might be having internet access issues. Are you running the above in test kitchen or on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Matt Wrock from Chef who sent me the answer:

> If you are trying to install .net 3.5 via test kitchen, use the
>   elevated winrm transport. This will allow .net 3.5 to be accessed via
>   windows update without the need for pointing at a source file. Remove
>   the source argument from your dism command and add this to your
>   .kitchen.yml:

```
transport:
  name: winrm
  elevated: true
```

After adding `elevated: true` to the .kitchen.yml file, I have successfully installed .NET 3.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 in Test Kitchen with the following code in the recipe. The same recipe works in Chef Client on the production box.

```
  powershell_script 'install_dot_net_3-5' do
    code <<-EOH
      Install-WindowsFeature -name NET-Framework-Core
    EOH
  end
```